# Your build failed to run: Couldn't read commit xxxxxxxx

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to build and deploy an image on GCP with cloud build.
I have a rails api repo on bitbucket running on docker, the repo is synced with google cloud repository

I configured a trigger on cloud build when a commit is made on my master branch.

Trigger Configuration:

[image: Trigger Configuration]

Service account permissions:

[image: Service account permissions]

But when the master branch gets a commit, the triggers returns the following error:
`our build failed to run: <br>Couldn't read commit xxxxxxxx`

Build Error:

[image: Build Error]

I tried checked the GCP doc and I can't find anything. I think the issue might be on the IAM level, maybe the service account needs more credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually edited the IAM setting for this service account to add:
Project > Editor
Source Repository > Reader

Now it works

Comment: can you elaborate on what this means? I don't see this as an option in IAM permissions

Comment: @KevinDanikowski did you go to the IAM section on GCP ?

Answer (score 2):

For me the Cloud Build API needed to be enabled.  Once I did this my build ran, I didn't need to do anything special for permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: More information is here @Community https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api